# Copy few rows from a Big list and all the columns should be Followed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Challenge I have 12 Months Bank statement and I have to select and Bifurcate the expenses.

There are many filters suppose I select rows by the filter "PURCHASE SUBJECT: MCUPOS"  There comes 79 Rows when I do **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>** all rows in that Particular columns are selected, But what I want is that all columns in these rows should be also selected before i copy.

How to do that?

This Video will help to understand-
http://screencast.com/t/uR9zDuB0dwI

Comment: SHIFT+SPACEBAR Select the entire row But this works only only on one row not all 73 rows that i have selected through CTRL+A

Answer (score 0):

How about Ctrl+Shift+[Right Arrow] and then Ctrl+Shift+[Up or Down Arrow]? ...Hold all these keys when selecting, and then let up off the arrow keys when your highlighted area reaches the size you want.

This will let you highlight from one side of a sheet to another, and then you can essentially tell Excel to continue highlighting up/down the selected range.

Hope this helps!

Or if you just want to select every single row in a particulat column, you can click on the very top of the column, where the Columns are denoted with letters, A, B, C, etc... and click the mouse once your pointer turns into a down arrow. This will highlight all the rows of a particular column. From there you can right click to copy, or use Ctrl+C.